# Shorter way to manipulate region of two-dimensional list

Tags: python, arrays, list, region

In an image processing app I am writing, I have a multidimensional list, `data`, and I need to be able to access a range of points (say a 2x2 block) at once.

At the moment I am using this:

> ```
> data[x, y] = average
>
> data[x+1, y] = average
>
> data[x, y+1] = average
>
> data[x+1, y+1] = average
> ```

But it's clunky, and if I wanted to expand to a 4x4 or 8x8 block it take 16 or 64 lines of code respectively.

There must be an easier, pythonic way to manipulate regions of a two dimensional list, any ideas?

Comment: If you have a list, `data[x, y]` shouldn't work.  Are you using a numpy `ndarray` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an actual 2D list, iterate through the indices you want to use:

```
for x in xrange(low_x, low_x+2):
    for y in xrange(low_y, low_y+2):
        data[x][y] = average
```

For a NumPy array, use a slice assignment:

```
data[x:x+2, y:y+2] = average
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using PIL and didn't realise it was a NumPy array - d'oh!

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as I can - 2 minutes from now